# Convert Random \frac{a}{b} to Float? Is the question phrased properly?

Tags: random-numbers, floating-point

How do I convert a randomly selected fraction in the [string?] form `\frac{a}{b}` to a [float?] form so that `pgf` can do calculations with it?

I am creating an exercise in which students practice determining the equation of randomly generated lines.

First a random fraction is selected to be the slope. That fraction displays as expected in equations, but I believe it cannot be used to calculate y-values of a plot in `TikZ`.

How do I fix this?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgf}
 \pgfmathsetseed{\number\pdfrandomseed}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\usepackage{tikz}

\pgfmathdeclarerandomlist{FracSlopes}
{%
 {\frac{1}{2}}
 {\frac{3}{2}}
 {\frac{5}{2}}
 {\frac{7}{2}}
 {\frac{1}{3}}
 {\frac{2}{3}}
 {\frac{4}{3}}
 {\frac{5}{3}}
 {\frac{7}{3}}
}

\pgfmathrandomitem{\FracSlope}{FracSlopes}




\begin{document}

% Since the line below works
% I know the fraction is being selected randomly.
\(y=\FracSlope{x}\) 

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.3]
\draw[help lines, gray, thin] (-10,-10) grid (10,10);
\draw[very thick,<->] (-10.3,0)--(10.3,0);
\draw[very thick,<->] (0,-10.3)--(0,10.3);
%
% Everythig compiles if the next two lines are commented out.
\clip (-10,-10) rectangle (10,10);
 \draw[blue, very thick, domain=-10:10] plot (\x,\FracSlope*\x);
 % It's interpreting \FracSlope as a string, not a number.
 % I'm *pretty* sure that's the problem.
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't use `\frac` in the context of a computation. But you can do it in an indirect fashion.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\pgfmathsetseed{\number\pdfrandomseed}

\pgfmathdeclarerandomlist{FracSlopes}
{%
 {\rfrac{1}{2}}
 {\rfrac{3}{2}}
 {\rfrac{5}{2}}
 {\rfrac{7}{2}}
 {\rfrac{1}{3}}
 {\rfrac{2}{3}}
 {\rfrac{4}{3}}
 {\rfrac{5}{3}}
 {\rfrac{7}{3}}
}

\pgfmathrandomitem{\FracSlope}{FracSlopes}

\newcommand{\rfrac}{\frac}
\newcommand{\computefrac}[2]{(#1/#2)}


\begin{document}

% Since the line below works
% I know the fraction is being selected randomly.
\(y=\FracSlope x\) 

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.3]
\let\rfrac\computefrac
\draw[help lines, gray, thin] (-10,-10) grid (10,10);
\draw[very thick,<->] (-10.3,0)--(10.3,0);
\draw[very thick,<->] (0,-10.3)--(0,10.3);
%
% Everythig compiles if the next two lines are commented out.
\clip (-10,-10) rectangle (10,10);
 \draw[blue, very thick, domain=-10:10] plot (\x,{\FracSlope*\x});
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Why this indirection? Since these fractions need to be used in different contexts and with different output, it's better to name them with a special command, which is set to expand to `\frac`, unless `\let\rfrac\computefrac` is issued (this will hold in the group). You can still use `\frac` in the `tikzpicture` environment, because this is not touched by the redefinitions.

Comment: Ok, this seems to work. Can I ask what `\mfrac` does? I looked it up on Google and in the `nccmath` package manual, but it seemed to be referencing *font sizes*.

Comment: @WeCanLearnAnything I added some comments about the code. The name was arbitrary.